# Find pandas quartiles based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
Av_Temp Tot_Precip
278.001 0
274     0.0751864
270.294 0.631634
271.526 0.229285
272.246 0.0652201
273     0.0840059
270.463 0.0602944
269.983 0.103563
268.774 0.0694555
269.529 0.010908
270.062 0.043915
271.982 0.0295718
```

I want to find the percentile values (25%, 50%, 75%) for the column: 'Tot_Precip' for each decile (top 10%, next 10% ...) of values from the column: Av_Temp. Currently, I am doing this:

```
import numpy, pandas, pdb
expl_var = 'Av_Temp'
cname    = 'Tot_Precip'
num_samples = 10.0
max_val = df[expl_var].max()
min_val = df[expl_var].min()

expl_bins = numpy.linspace(min_val, max_val, num = num_samples)

for index, val in enumerate(expl_bins):
    print index
    if index < (len(expl_bins) - 1):
        cur_val = val
        nxt_val = expl_bins[index+1]

        # Subset dataframe to rows with values of expl_var between
        # cur_val and nxt_val
        sub_ind_df = df[(df[expl_var] >= cur_val) & (df[expl_var] <= nxt_val)]

        sub_ind_df[cname+'_quartiles'] = pandas.qcut(sub_ind_df[cname], 4)
        # Merge with sub_df
        pdb.set_trace()
```

Not sure how to proceed after this.

The answer could be something like:

```
Av_Temp_decile     Tot_Precip_25      Tot_Precip_50    Tot_Precip_75
270 - 272           0.03                  0.05               0.08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only splitting you data into halves rather than deciles here due to the small example dataset, but everything should work the same if you just increase the number of bins in the initial cut:

```
# Change this to 10 to get deciles
df['Temp_Halves'] = pd.qcut(df['Av_Temp'], 2)

def get_quartiles(group):
    # Add retbins=True to get the bin edges
    qs, bins = pd.qcut(group['Tot_Precip'], [.25, .5, .75], retbins=True)
    # Returning a series from a function means groupby.apply() will 
    #   expand it into separate columns
    return pd.Series(bins, index=['Precip_25', 'Precip_50', 'Precip_75']

df.groupby('Temp_Halves').apply(get_quartiles)
Out[21]: 
                    Precip_25  Precip_50  Precip_75
Temp_Halves                                        
[268.774, 270.995]   0.048010   0.064875   0.095036
(270.995, 278.001]   0.038484   0.070203   0.081801
```