# Overlapping boxplots in python

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
Av_Temp Tot_Precip
278.001 0
274     0.0751864
270.294 0.631634
271.526 0.229285
272.246 0.0652201
273     0.0840059
270.463 0.0602944
269.983 0.103563
268.774 0.0694555
269.529 0.010908
270.062 0.043915
271.982 0.0295718
```

and want to plot a boxplot where the x-axis is 'Av_Temp' divided into equi-sized bins (say 2 in this case), and the Y-axis shows the corresponding range of values for Tot_Precip. I have the foll. code (thanks to [Find pandas quartiles based on another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428043/find-pandas-quartiles-based-on-another-column/32429661#32429661)), however, when I plot the boxplots, they are getting plotted one on top of another. Any suggestions?

```
expl_var = 'Av_Temp'
cname = 'Tot_Precip'
df[expl_var+'_Deciles'] = pandas.qcut(df[expl_var], 2)
grp_df = df.groupby(expl_var+'_Deciles').apply(lambda x: numpy.array(x[cname]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(grp_df)):
    box_arr = grp_df[i]
    box_arr = box_arr[~numpy.isnan(box_arr)]
    stats = cbook.boxplot_stats(box_arr, labels = str(i))

    ax.bxp(stats)
    ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using pandas already, why not use the boxplot method on dataframes?

```
expl_var = 'Av_Temp'
cname = 'Tot_Precip'
df[expl_var+'_Deciles'] = pandas.qcut(df[expl_var], 2)

ax = df.boxplot(by='Av_Temp_Deciles', column='Tot_Precip')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

That produces this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/20KPx.png

If you don't like the labels, throw in a

```
plt.xlabel('');plt.suptitle('');plt.title('')
```

If you want a standard boxplot, the above should be fine.  My understanding of the separation of boxplot into boxplot_stats and bxp is to allow you to modify or replace the stats generated and fed to the plotting routine.  See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2643 for some details.

If you need to draw a boxplot with non-standard stats, you can use boxplot_stats on 2D numpy arrays, so you only need to call it once.  No loops required.

```
expl_var = 'Av_Temp'
cname = 'Tot_Precip'
df[expl_var+'_Deciles'] = pandas.qcut(df[expl_var], 2)

# I moved your nan check into the df apply function
grp_df = df.groupby('Av_Temp_Deciles').apply(lambda x: numpy.array(x[cname][~numpy.isnan(x[cname])]))

# boxplot_stats can take a 2D numpy array of data, and a 1D array of labels
# stats is now a list of dictionaries of stats, one dictionary per quantile 
stats = cbook.boxplot_stats(grp_df.values, labels=grp_df.index)

# now it's a one-shot plot, no loops
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bxp(stats)
ax.set_yscale('log')
```